# Unix formatting text into table with grep or awk or sed

Tags: unix

I have been able to locate things no problem with `grep` however the assignment is basically pulling data out and formatting it and displaying it as a table columns with multiple rows.  Now it shouldn't be anything crazy because we only have basic knowledge of `awk` and `sed`.  Now I'm curious: is there any way to take my output from `grep` and format it so for example I get:

```
Jake
0001
Bob
0002
Kim
0003
```

and want to make it something like this

```
#     Name   LD #
---   ----   ----
  1   Jake   0001 
  2   Bob    0002
  3   Kim    0003
```

Also is it possible to explain each part of your line and also is it possible to make it expandable if I have a large record to deal with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and read about MCVEs ([MCVE]). How do you know which lines start a new record?  Are the number of fields (lines) per record strictly fixed, or could 'Joe' be followed by 'Sue'?  How do you know which column headings to apply?  Do you need to allow for 'Ozymandias' to turn up in the list of names at something like record 3000 whereas everyone else is 3 or 4 characters wide?  Of the tools listed, `awk` is the obvious candidate; it can deal with the issues as long you can specify an algorithm.  But your requirements are as yet unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the headings were assigned in the project so basically they are listed in order based on how i used grep to pull each record

Answer (score 1):

You need to defined (or identify) a control logic that matches your grep output.

Derived from what you gave I assume the following:

- the heading is a constant text that is intrinsic to your formatting
  (Not to be deduced from input)
- the first column is an ordinal number starting with one
- the records from the input are identified by a string of all digits

Then the following awk script will do the formatting:

```
BEGIN {
    # initialize ordinal
    ordinal=1;
    # print heading
    printf "%-3s %5s %4s\n", "#", "Name", "LD #"
}
# match trigger line for output 
/^[0-9]+$/ { printf "%3d %5s %4s\n", ordinal++, label, $1;
             # cleanou label - not necessary for single data item case
             # we are done with this input line
             next;
}
# collect data item
{
    label=$1;
    # we are done with this input line
    next;
}
```

If you want to include more record items (leading to more columns) you might check whether the preceeding column values have been encountered.

Or even just use a counter for indicating at what column you are within your record.

Then you could use e.g.:

```
BEGIN {
    # initialize ordinal
    ordinal=1;
    column=0;
    # print heading
    printf "%-3s %5s %4s\n", "#", "Name", "LD #"
}
# match trigger line for output
/^[0-9]+$/ { printf "%3d (%d)", ordinal++, column;
             for (i=0; i < column; i++) {
                 printf " %s", data[i];
                 data[i] = "";
             }
             printf "\n";
             # we are done with this input line
             column=0;
             next;
}
# collect data item
{
    data[column++]=$1;
    if (length($1) > max[column]) {
        max[column]=length($1);
    }
    # we are done with this input line
    next;
}

END {
     for (i=0; i< length(max); i++)  {
         printf "Col %d: %d\n", i, max[i];
     }
}
```

I also included a way of determining the size of the columns (character count).

Comment: fantastic work now what would idea if lets say instead of just jake its   jaskson, jake D. how would be able to place that under name if that possible with this code

Comment: You are refering to have proper size of the columns? This is task of the number values of the formats in printf. For asjusting this to wider columns you would follow 2 approaches: guess a proper width upfront and use the values. Or, make a 2-pass run first pass determining the sizes (and building the records) and second path doing the formatting.

Comment: OK cool then I will be probably guessing the length just because I am definitely not sure how to do 2pass run but also quick question, how exactly do u scale this up to do multiple columns? So let's say you want 8 columns so it would be like 1 Jackson Jack d 0001 paper grade 4.000 book.    For each do I just need to add enough characters for each during the print or do I need to select another variable keep in mind that these items are inside a variable I can output them too a file if that makes it easier... So for the confusing question still learning awk

Comment: OK fantastic thanks so much also all your assumption are correct like with the number to the left its added in with the loop ect!

Comment: Ok i am having a few issues with this first how do i get awk to read the items from a variable not a file and then it keeps giving me 'BEGIN: command not found'  then syntax error near unexpected token '}'  which is line 7 of your code... not sure what i did wrong if might be able to assist here that would be great sorry for more confusion

Comment: How do you run our script? `gawk -f script` is the way to go if you do not use `#!/_path_/gawk -f` as first line (with unix like systems). `BEGIN` is the pattern that is being executed before the first line, while `END` is the pattern that is matchin after the last line.. If you have a variable, whey would you want to read the data? You just should set the values properly in the first place.

Comment: Well see i stored them into a variable for testing because i exacted them from a long document and then put them into a variable and then need to format it but thats what i am trying to figure out.  Would it be possible to echo the variable and pipe it into the gawk -f script? to be able to achieve this sorry for the confusion

Comment: Exactly this is the way to go. gawk 8as any uniy tool) is reading files or stdin and writes to stdout by default. Put your test data into a file and read the lines from the file: `gawk -f script < testdata`

Comment: ok so here is the issue i keep facing and I am clueless so for example the name is Jackson, Jake D.  when i go to print this variable and give it space 17 to be exact it will give 17 spaces to the last name only and not carry the first name or middle letter? do you have any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: looks like something is splittimg at `,`. To avoid this replace the occurrences of `$1`  (first field) by `$0` (entire input record)